# Como agrupar pela coluna somente quando ela não for null (Oracle)?

Tags: sql, oracle, null, group-by

A query está resumida para facilitar:

```sql
SELECT
    nome,idade,profissao,cidade, bairro, estado, pais
FROM objeto
group by  nome,idade,profissao,cidade, bairro, estado, pais;
```

Porém 3 colunas podem vim `null` (`profissao`, `bairro`, `estado`). Quando alguma dessas colunas vier `null`, a coluna `null` não deve ser utilizada no agrupamento dos registros, deverar agrupar pelas que estão `not null`.

Ou seja, (`profissao`, `bairro`, `estado`) poderão vir nulas ou não, mas precisam ser agrupadas também por elas quando vier `not null`.

Comment: não pode usar um `where`  para filtrar?

Comment: Negócio é o seguinte. Não tem choradeira. Se quer que não agrupe por null, então não pode vir null nessas colunas, simples assim. Senão vai agrupar por null. Acrescente nos seus WHERE as cláusulas AND NomeColuna IS NOT NULL e seja feliz. Se desse pra fazer alguma gambiarra, seria no HAVING do GROUP BY, mas acredito que não dê.

Comment: Entendi. Mas se eu colocar o " WHERE as cláusulas AND NomeColuna IS NOT NULL", ele não vai trazer os registros que tiverem alguma coluna null, e eu preciso deles. Por ex, uma das colunas é de valor, ae eu precisaria dela agrupada se as outras colunas que estão not null forem iguais

Comment: Tente algo como nvl(coluna,'sem informacao') no agrupamento.

Comment: Por este seu exemplo será que `SELECT DISTINCT nome,idade,profissao,cidade, bairro, estado, pais FROM objeto` não atenderia? Pode ser que sua simplificação tenha dificultado o entendimento.

Comment: pq um group by se não tem nenhuma função de agregação ?

Comment: concordo com o @RovannLinhalis se o select não usa agregação não há necessidade de group by... se estiver usando para eliminar duplicatas use a sugestão do `DISTINCT` acima que é a forma correta de fazer isso